# Oreo - issue when rotating a device within a fragment with a listView (plus an asyncTask)

Tags: android, listview, android-8.0-oreo, screen-rotation

I'm creating a listview in a fragment and rotate the device. It works well except on Oreo.

At runtime it does not complain and I see my list. Then I rotate and I don't see the list anymore. Prior to Oreo the code below works as it is: after rotating the device I can still see my list correctly.

To make the small example works I had to add the re-creation of the list (code commented out so that you can test with lower than O version) in onResume.

It seems that I'm missing a call to refresh the view when I rotate. I get a blank screen in place of my ListView.

I can't find some oreo documentation that explains the way to deal with listview on device's rotation? or tuto/example? I use a List/adapter mechanism.

What has changed in Oreo?

Fragment code:

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {
    private ListView listView;
    private List<ListItems> listItems;
    private ListAdapter listAdapter;


    public ListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.i("ROT","onResume");
/*
        String[] name = {"linux","win","android" };

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), listItems);
        listView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview);

        for(int i=0;i<name.length;i++){
            ListItems items = new ListItems();
            items.setOsName(name[i]);
            listItems.add(items);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
*/
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("ROT","onCreateView");
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Log.i("ROT","onActivityCreated");

        String[] name = {"linux","win","android" };

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), listItems);
        listView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview);

        for(int i=0;i<name.length;i++){
            ListItems items = new ListItems();
            items.setOsName(name[i]);
            listItems.add(items);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }

    }

}
```

Here is my Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ListFragment listFragment = new ListFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, listFragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

The items creation:

```
    public class ListItems {
        private String osName;

        String getOsName(){
            return osName;
        }

        void setOsName(String s){
            osName = s;
        }
    }
```

The adapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static List<ListItems> listItems;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    ListAdapter(Context context, List<ListItems> objects) {
        listItems = objects;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewIPHolder {
        TextView os;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewIPHolder viewHolder;

        if(convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewIPHolder();

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list, null);

            viewHolder.os = convertView.findViewById(R.id.osname);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewIPHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.os.setText(listItems.get(position).getOsName());

        return convertView;
    }


}
```

and finally the xml layout.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

layout_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

layout_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/osname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Are there some warnings / errors in logcat?

Comment: @rushi I rewid... there are somes. I'll edit the Q

Comment: Also, can you log if the listViewState is null or empty, And in genereal, you can follow https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/#startdebug to do step by step debugging and then provide exactly where the behaviour is different in oreo and others.

Comment: listViewstate has a value. If it didn't have it would crash on listTest.onRestoreInstanceState(listViewState); and the same code works fine on other android version. With Oreo it goes through the same sequence as M for ex.

Comment: can you do step by step debugging and figure out difference?

Comment: I did it already but rechecked for you. exactly the same: I rotate the device calls onSaveInstanceState then onCreateView as the savedInstanceState/listViewState/listTest are not null it restores the saved instance then recalls onCreateView this time the savedInstance is null. On both M and O. The listview doesn't show up on O.

Comment: From where you are getting data, from previous activity or you getting it in fragment itself.

Comment: no, in my fragment itself. I've done a simple app to mimic what I do. Without adding anything (not saving instance) it's rotating nicely on versions till N. The difference between N and O is that onResume is called last (I thought it was the case in all android versions?!?). So I added the re-creation of the listview in onResume and this works. I'm trying to do the same in my app but the sreen stays desperately blank. Something has definitely changed in the rotation.

Comment: Because your sent code is not sufficient to answer your question i down vote your answer; you have omitted important parts.  Also your code here has static items but your question is about dynamic items

Answer (score 0):

My solution works now and relies on resetting, after the rotation, the listview with setAdapter in onResume. This is the part that has changed in O. On top of this I use an asyncTask in the fragment to build the list. So setRetainInstance(true) makes it, when the device is rotated, from an asyncTask running conservation. The part that is tricky is to deal with the different case on what to redraw/reinitialize in onResume.

The workaround is really not as good as my actual (prior to O) solution. I had a simple/stupid solution which worked great and now I need to implement a complex code (re-drawing the listview is simple but not dealing with async task).

If there are Android folks reading those lines:

-O is really a great job but the ramp up to match the api changes are tough (ex: startforeground services, rotation)

-keep it simple: when you have an app like mine using several async tasks, threads and you want to deal with rotation, it's really not easy amongst other issues.

Comment: Down vote because your code in your question is not complete for any one to answer you. and again here you say you had done something and request a better solution but no one can see your code to see what is problem or even why this solution is working for you. any event in your fragment or activity could have some code that may be a key to answer you. but no one could see that thus no one can answer you.Also you have sent layouts but your problem is not relevant to any layout if you have same layout in portrait and landscape.

Comment: you need to send all codes that touches adapter and set or change adapter for `listview` and all codes of `AsyncTask` if you want any one to answer you. there is no special problem about Oreo on rotation that you are searching for.

Comment: when you are using multiple threads with error and you run your code N times you may get correct answer but on N+1 time you will see that error. you may have same error on pre Oreo Android but accidentally and unfortunately you have not see it.